# Hadoop 2.7.2 HA cluster unable to start standby namenode

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

I have configured Hadoop-2.7.2 HA cluster in windows. Facing the below exception when starting second namenode NN2 with **hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby** command

> STARTUP_MSG:   build = Unknown -r Unknown; compiled by 'Kumar' on 2016-01-2
>   8T06:05Z
>   STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_51
>   ************************************************************/
>   16/02/03 14:57:42 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-bootstrapStandby]
>   16/02/03 14:57:43 FATAL ha.BootstrapStandby: Unable to fetch namespace information from active NN at nn1:9000: Unknown method isUpgradeFinalized called on org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.NamenodeProtocol protocol.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:604)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1658)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
>   16/02/03 14:57:43 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 2
>   16/02/03 14:57:43 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
>   /************************************************************
>   SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at nn2

I have verified my configurations. With the same configuration, HA cluster works fine with Hadoop-2.7.1

Do i have missed any new configuration?
or
Any special command for hadoop-2.7.2 added to form HA cluster?

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Hadoop-2.7.2 refers old Tez jars which is built for hadoop-2.5.2. I have replaced Tez package and it works fine.

In Hadoop-2.7.1, it seems tez jars are not referred normally. But in Hadoop-2.7.2, Tez jars are referring and executing some methods from that.